# applying javascript vertical center to multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, center, vertical-alignment

After hours of trying to sort this out by myself i feel the need to turn to someone who knows better than me. I have a function that centers a child div within a parent div. It all works the only problem is the child div changes in size so i need a way of applying this function to every div individually.

here is my code

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner">short text in here</div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
<div class="inner">some text in here more text here that is longer. This is longer</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer{background:#eee;height:150px;width:150px;margin-bottom:20px;}
.inner{width:130px;padding:10px;text-align:center;}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var inner = $('.inner'),
ht = inner.height();

inner.css({'position':'absolute','top':'50%','margin':-ht/2+'px 0 0 0'});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AMNVY/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Does this work for you?](http://jsfiddle.net/AMNVY/3/)

All i did was edit the css:

```
.outer{
    background:#eee;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    display: table;
}
.inner{
    width:130px;
    padding:10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
```

}

no need for js...

Comment: thanks this worked for me although i did have to also add vertical-align: middle; to the inner div

Answer (score 1):

If you still need javascript here is my solution... You could use this bind to get height everytime it changes, then you should be able to create an algorithm to manage css.

JS:

```
$('#inner').bind('getheight', function() {
    $('#inner').height();
});
```